# TIBCO JMS SERVER : Redelivery count when using client ack mode

Tags: jms

RedeliveryLimit, which determines the number of times a message is redelivered after a recover or rollback.

I just wanted to confirm that we can control the redelivery limit for a message by the setting above in the jms server when calling  session.recover  for client acknowledgment mode.   From what I read it seems to be the way to set the limit.

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs81/jms/implement.html

Otherwise, I have to check for the "isRedelivered"  flag and acknowledge the message after it is redelivered once  to prevent any poison messages from getting redelivered again and again.

Comment: https://docs.tibco.com/pub/enterprise_message_service/6.1.0-august-2011/doc/html/tib_ems_api_reference/api/dotNETAdmin/html/P_TIBCO_EMS_ADMIN_QueueInfo_MaxRedelivery.htm